# Print specific words/numbers via grep/cut commands

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing

I have a file `test.txt`, which contains the following result:

```
service_name1= apple/ball/cat/dog/egg/12.34.56/ball/apple
service_name2= fan/girl/house/ice/joker/23.45.67/fan/girl
```

and so on up to `service_name1500`

I want output like :

```
egg 12.34.56
joker 23.45.67
```

and so on: the version number along with the word before that.

Comment: is it necessary to do it with grep? I'd use `sed` or `awk`

Answer (score 11):

This should be a simple `cut` job:

```
cut -d/ -f5,6 --output-delimiter=" "
```

- `-d/` sets the input delimiter as `/`
- `-f5,6` outputs only the 5th and 6th field
- `--output-delimiter=" "` sets the output delimiter as a space

---

Same thing with `awk`, `awk` by default sets the output field separator as space:

```
awk -F/ '{print $5,$6}'
```

---

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
service_name1= apple/ball/cat/dog/egg/12.34.56/ball/apple
service_name2= fan/girl/house/ice/joker/23.45.67/fan/girl

% cut -d/ -f5,6 --output-delimiter=" " file.txt
egg 12.34.56
joker 23.45.67

% awk -F/ '{print $5,$6}' file.txt
egg 12.34.56 
joker 23.45.67
```

Answer (score 8):

a `sed` solution (works whether the field position of the version string is consistent or not, but the form of the version string must be consistent)

```
$ sed -r 's#.*/(.*)/([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}).*#\1 \2#' test.txt
egg 12.34.56

joker 23.45.67
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` use ERE so we don't have to escape `()` metacharacters
- `s#old#new#` find pattern `old` and replace with `new`
- `.*` match any or no characters in this position
- `(stuff)` remember `stuff` for later
- `[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}` a pattern of [2 digits].[2 digits].[2 digits]
- `\1 \2` the two remembered patterns with a space in between

Answer (score 5):

This will do it:

```
cut -d'/' -f5-6 test.txt | tr -s "/" " "
```

Answer (score 3):

If you deal with fixed word positions this would work:

```
grep -e 'service_name[0-9]*=' test.txt|awk -F'/' '{ print $5" "$6 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sed -r 's/.*\/([[:alpha:]]+)\/([\.0-9]*)\/.*/\1 \2/' test.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*` at the beginning and end cuts all characters that do not match the following
- `([[:alpha:]]+)` first subgroup in brackets matches only alphabetical characters
- `\/` matches a slash which will be cut out
- next subgroup `([\.0-9]*)` matches numbers and points and stores it in the second register
- after the single slash `/` comes the substitution with `\1 \2` inserts the first and second register from the matched subgroups

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy but working python one-liner:

```
$ python -c "import sys;print '\n'.join([ ' '.join(l.strip().split('/')[4:6]) for l in sys.stdin])" < input.txt          
egg 12.34.56
joker 23.45.67
```

How it works:

- redirect input file with `<` into python's stdin stream
- use list comprehension `[item for item in sequence]` to read stdin line by line
- `.split()` lets us break down lines into list of words using `/` as separator
- extract words 4 and 5 ( the [4:6] implies last number is not inclusive ) and make a string out of them using `' '.join()`
- having made list of strings that we want, turn them into lines using `'\n'.join()` , and print it all out